# How to populate new output variables in terraform state file?

Tags: terraform

This is a snippet of my terraform TF file

```
// main "parent" module
// a list of email addresses for alert emails
variable "alertees" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

I want to expose this attribute to other module via data "terraform_remote_state"

For example, in a subfolder I want to be able to reuse the above attribute like this

```
// module in subfolder
data "terraform_remote_state" "parent" {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "../parent.tfstate"
  }
}

module "custom_resource" {
  source = "../../../custom_resource"
  ...
  alertees = parent.parent
}
```

However I think because there is no resource to create, the `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` simply quitted after reporting "No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date."

Is there anyway I can get these values committed into the state files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terraform 0.12 and earlier, `terraform plan` doesn't consider changes to outputs to be a side-effect needing to be applied, as you saw.

You can use `terraform refresh` to populate new outputs, but that may also cause other things in your state to be updated because it will resynchronize the state values with the remote objects.

Terraform 0.13 (which is in beta at the time I'm writing this) changes this behavior so that changes to output values *are* considered changes that can be planned and applied. Once using Terraform 0.13 you can use a more conventional workflow: add or update the `output` blocks in the configuration, and then run `terraform apply` to preview the effect of the change and choose whether to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `terraform refresh` to populate the outputs into the state file.